# How do I view what version of samba I am running for my domain controler?

Tags: samba

Is there a command line way to see what version of Samba I am running?

Comment: Please make sure you're running 4.6.4/4.5.10/4.4.14 or up, to avoid the critical CVE-2017-7494 vulnerability ("**SambaCry**").

Comment: And 4.13.17, 4.14.12 and 4.15.5 for [CVE-2021-44142](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2021-44142.html), and surely others in future.

Answer (score 36):

Use the `smbstatus` command from the shell to get an output like this `Samba version 3.0.25b-1.el5_1.4`

Comment: +1 but I would run `smbstatus --version` otherwise you'll get a lot of output on a busy server.

Answer (score 27):

Just enter below command on your terminal

```
smbd -V
```

Comment: Works! Don't understand the downvote.

Comment: idk, I just tried this command and it gave me the Linux kernel version if you run it from Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This command gives the Samba version and not the SMB version.  Already upvoted.  Maybe someone is misunderstanding the difference between the smbd (Samba daemon) and SMB (Communication protocol).

Comment: I just tried in Debian 9.13 and both `smbd -V` and `smbstatus` show exactly the same version, this case *Samba version 4.13.13-Debian*

Answer (score 4):

For the Linux Samba version type :

```
$ smbstatus -V
Version 4.6.14-SerNet-RedHat-16.el7
```

But I guess your domain controller needs is the SMB Protocol version you are using, you can find it by typing :

```
# smbstatus -p
PID     Username     Group        Machine                           Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
226861  nobody       nogroup      10.0.0.55 (ipv4:10.0.0.55:61866)  SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)
```